# Sum each attributes value from api response javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to sum up all the similar attributes from api response.

[image]

Comment: `var sum = activities.reduce((s, act) => +act.points_earned + s, 0);`

Comment: use `reduce` to sum. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: So loop over the array...

Comment: @4castle slight edit since `points_earned` appears to be strings for non-zero values: `var sum = activities.reduce((s, { points_earned: pe }) => Number(pe) + s, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some kind of loop. One solution is to use `forEach` where `data` variable is the array you received from your api response.

```js
var sum=0;
var data=[{points_earned:"2"},{points_earned:4}]
data.forEach(function(elem){
sum+=Number(elem.points_earned);
});
console.log(sum);


var sumUsingReduce=0;
var total = data.reduce(function(sum, value) {
  return sumUsingReduce += Number(value.points_earned)
}, 0);

console.log(sumUsingReduce);
```

```
var sum=0;
data.forEach(function(elem){
sum+=elem.points_earned;
});
```

Others also suggested using **reduce**:

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

Example:

```
var total = [0, 1, 2, 3].reduce(function(sum, value) {
  return sum + value;
}, 0);
```

Comment: While this is perfectly valid, I think that `reduce()` would be the most canonical approach here for a many-to-one calculation.

Comment: I can access the value at `EachPointSummary.points_earned` how can i use this using reduce.

Answer (score 4):

Your API is responding with an array of objects. Therefore you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over that array and sum the value of the points_earned property of each object.

```
const sum = responseArray.reduce((currentSum, nextObject) => {

  // Note that you need to coerce points_earned
  // to a Number or it will simply concatenate the strings
  return currentSum + +nextObject.points_earned;

// 0 is your initial value used by currentSum in
// the first iteration
}, 0);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vto7za2s/1/)

Comment: why in my case it says `EachPointSummary.reduce` is not a function. whereas I can access the `points_earned` from `EachPointSummary.points_earned`

Comment: @Santosh,  I've clarified my answer to hopefully help you understand what's going on.